# Capturing specific fields on a long string

Tags: regex

I'm a little bit stuck here...

I'm working to parse some information that looks like this (CouchDB database content):

```
rows=[{"id":"AGO","key":"AGO","value":{"rev":"1-78f969c9a3f590d11c78d711558b393d"}},{"id":"ALB","key":"ALB","value":{"rev":"1-ecb0ea637ac64ed98d895a268dbe1edf"}},{"id":"ARE","key":"ARE","value":{"rev":"1-8b863c318c3f818f6597b71b7e336535"}},{"id":"ARG","key":"ARG","value":{"rev":"1-a443a4968d8345f723a8c4c7dbd11239"}},{"id":"ARM","key":"ARM","value":{"rev":"1-56eebce5411ba54c49258a690fa46c44"}}]
```

This is one long line.

what I'm trying to do is to create a Regex that can help me to get the "id" field. So the output should be something like this:

```
AGO
ALB
ARE
ARG
ARM
```

I know this would be easy if we only have one line `("id":"(\w+{3})")`, but how can I create a regex that that repeats itself over the string?

Comment: Why regex? What language are you doing this in? Use a Parser instead.

Comment: Do you have to use a regex? It would probably be easier if you decoded this JSON to a native data structure and the just iterated over the "id" keys. What language is it?

Comment: pass the global modifier `g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do it in regex and you have access to that data in the string presented, this matches your IDs:

```
(?<="id":")[^"]*(?=")
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rT9rJ5)

- The lookbehind `(?<="id":")` asserts that we are preceded by `"id":"`
- The negative character class `[^"]*` matches the ID: any characters that are not a double quote
- The lookahead `(?=")` asserts that what follows is a double quote

Comment: FYI, added explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

The below regex will capture all the id's if your language supports `\K`.

```
\"id":\"\K([^"]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pI1rN9)

**Explanation:**

```
\"id":\"    #  Matches "id":"

\K          #  Used to discard the previous matches. So "id":" got discarded.

([^"]*)     #  Matches all the characters except " zero or more times.
```